# Kafka kafka-producer-perf-test.sh NetworkException The server disconnected before a response was received

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to perform a benchmark test in our kafka env. I have played with few configurations such as request.timeout.ms and max.block.ms and throughout but not able to avoid the error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 148 record(s) for benchmark-6-3r-2isr-none-0: 182806 ms has passed since last append
```

Produce Perf Test command:

```
nohup sh ~/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic benchmark-6p-3r-2isr-none --num-records 10000000 --record-size 100 --throughput 1000 --print-metrics --producer-props acks=all bootstrap.servers=node1:9092,node2:9092,node3:9092 request.timeout.ms=180000 max.block.ms=180000 buffer.memory=100000000 > ~/kafka/load_test/results/6p-3r-10M-100B-t-1-ackall-rto3m-block2m-bm100m-2 2>&1
```

Cluster: 3 nodes, topic: 6 partitions, RF=3 and minISR=2
I am monitoring the kafka metrics using a tsdb and grafana. I know that disk IO perf is bad [disk await(1.5 secs), IO queue size and disk utilization metrics are high(60-75%)] but I don't see any issue in kafka logs that can relate slow disk io to the above perf errors.

But I get the error even for 1000 messages/sec.

Need suggestions to understand the issue and fix the above errors?

I have another very disturbing observation.

The errors go away if I start 2 kafka-producer-perf-test.sh with the same configs on different hosts. 
If I cancel 1 kafka-producer-perf-test.sh then after some time the above errors start reappearing.